# Please clarify why this question was closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

Please clarify why this question was closed:

[R functions for identifying dates of particular kinds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584893/r-functions-for-identifying-dates-of-particular-kinds)

The reason cited was "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more." However, I didn't ask for a recommendation for someone's favorite functions for doing XYZ; I simply asked whether functions *existed* that did XYZ.

Furthermore, the phrasing of my question "R functions for identifying dates of particular kinds?" is virtually identical to the sample question in the query box after one clicks the "Ask a question" button: "Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?"

Comment: _"We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, __software libraries__, and more."_ and you're asking _"whether there is a package that already does this"_... That's just not on-topic on SO.

Comment: I don't mean to be daft, but "whether something exists" is not the same thing as a recommendation. A recommendation is an opinion. Whether something exists is a fact. The two are not the same.

Comment: So, you get an answer _"Yea, it exists"_, or _"Nah, it doesn't exist"_... Then what?

Comment: Ideally, the name of the package.

Comment: Which is a recommendation: _"Yea, take a look at <library name here>"_

Comment: Disagree. It's a fact.

Comment: And the name of the package is...what exactly? A recommendation, no? More to the point - *the reason* asking for resources is not allowed is because these lists become out of date fast and are not maintainable.

Comment: You're free to disagree, but that's simply how that rule works on Stack Overflow. Questions asking for software libraries are quick to get outdated, impossible to maintain and unlikely to help future visitors, and as such, not allowed on SO.

Comment: You could easily make this on-topic by providing a reproducible example of your data, saying you want to identify all dates that are the "first weekday of any month", showing what you tried and then where you got stuck. That is the Q&A format which should be followed here.

Comment: If you "ideally" don't want a yes or no answer, don't ask a yes or no question.

Answer (score 24):

Your question says: *"I am just curious whether there is a package that already does this sort of thing more efficiently/flexibly."* So you are asking for a software library.

I think you are getting caught up on the word "recommendations". It doesn't matter whether what you're asking for is people's subjective judgement, because questions asking for a library that does something are automatically off-topic. Unfortunately the message you were shown doesn't communicate this very well, but the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is clearer (emphasis mine):

> Questions asking us to recommend **or find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

So it doesn't matter whether an answer would be a "recommendation" or not. That said, it definitely involves making some kind of opinion or judgement to claim that a library does something "more efficiently/flexibly" than some other option. It would be totally reasonable to describe a hypothetical answer like "You can use library XYZ, it is efficient and flexible" as a recommendation for library XYZ.

The fact that your title has a similar wording to a different question that would be on-topic, doesn't make your question on-topic. What makes a question on-topic is defined in the help centre, linked above.